# What is the easiest and most cost effective way to turn a 1 bedroom apartment into 2 bedrooms?

Tags: walls, sound-proofing, bedroom, rental, partition

Obviously, I could build a full wall with insulation, etc.; however, this might not even be allowed, and even if it is, there are a variety of factors why it is not ideal like the time to build it and it is not very cost effective. Further, if I ever moved, removing an entire wall is no easy task.

What are some good ways to build a room into a 2 bedroom apartment, which has walls and doesn't bleed sound and has a door? I'm wondering if there is a better way besides framing out an entire wall.

Electrical isn't an issue because I just won't put any outlets or anything onto the dividing wall(s). No need to make things more complicated than they need to be.

I think the greatest factors when choosing how to do it, is:

- sound penetration (as soundproof as possible, maybe use some [green glue](http://www.greengluecompany.com/)
- wall stability (has to be sturdy enough so that falling into it won't knock it down! And so you can hang things up on it)
- ease of removing/portability if I decide to move
- privacy - I want my apartment mate to feel safe and secure

Where I live, a 2 bedroom BEGINS AT $2,000 (up to $20,000). So instead of spending all my paychecks on rent, I thought maybe a 1 bedroom could be a better option. I just don't want to rent "my couch" to an apartment mate. I want to be very fair and give them their own room.

Comment: Please do try to be nice. If you don't like an answer, you can down vote it and leave a nice comment as to why that solution will not work for you. Thank you, and have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your existing room already happens to have two doors then the project that you propose is never going to get any where because the project is more than trying to build some divider wall.

Trying to cut an additional doorway into the room is just not something you can freely do to a property that you happen to be renting.

Additionally the requirements you have placed on the performance of the divider wall would require that you build in a good solid wall. This is simply not something you can do to a property that you are renting.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you are located this is probably not legal. In the USA in most building jurisdictions every bedroom has to have an exterior escape (ie. a window that meets the size requirements for a human to escape through).  Also, USA NEC electrical code requires receptacles to be placed so that no point along the floor/wall line is more than 6 feet from a receptacle.  A divider in a building is a wall and it must be built as such and properly secured to the existing structure.

Comment: I wouldn't make a room without a window., Of course, I would make it where a window already exists. This goes without saying.